# Symmetric tensor of Lie algebra of $su(N)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, gauge-theory

I am interested in knowing the exact form of the anti-commutation of two generators of $su(N)$ lie algebra.

Let us denote $T^a$ to be the generator of $su(N)$ lie algebra in the defining representation. Since the number of generators is $n^2-1$, the index takes value in $a=1, ..., n-1$.  The normalization of $T^a$ is 
$$Tr(T^aT^b)=\frac{1}{2} \delta^{ab}$$
The anti commutation of two such generators is
$$\{T^a, T^b\}=T^a T^b+T^bT^a=\frac{1}{N}\delta^{ab}I+d^{abc}T^c$$
where $d^{abc}$ is a totally symmetric tensor in all the three indices. In https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1101/914fc76a36d4fb0ab0022f8c4ec6295d8d1f.pdf,  it was shown that 
$$d^{abc}d^{abh}=\frac{N^2-4}{N}\delta^{ch}$$
where the repeated indices are to be summed over. In the above, we contract over two indices from each $d$-tensor.

My questions are:

1) Is there a simple expression for
$$d^{abc}d^{agh}$$
where we only contract one index for each $d$-tensor? (in terms of $N$)

2) Is there a simple expression for 
$d^{abc}$
itself? (in terms of $N$)

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422141/2451

Comment: Math mods: please merge with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881730/11127.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand from the [physics analog of this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422141/symmetric-tensor-of-lie-algebra-of-sun) that you accept (2) is a basis-dependent subjective vortex.  For (1), also subjective, yes and no. *N* is actually the least of your problems, and you might fix it by extrapolation of the generic results of [MacFarlane, Sundry, and Weisz, 1968](https://idp.springer.com/authorize/casa?redirect_uri=https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01654302.pdf&casa_token=bb91Pnweh9wAAAAA:DoiTvG_tXx3ZqqxQe4ygtQFXitgdOSYPAD2izny6pPqEZLoRmduljCrF-6s3yk8sMHQVtW-p3FRDfjGV), (2.23), for SU(3), 
$$
3d_{ijk}d_{pqk}= \delta_{ip} \delta_{jq} + \delta_{iq}  \delta_{jp}-  \delta_{ij}  \delta_{pq} + f_{ipm} f_{jqm}+  f_{iqm} f_{jpm}  ~.
$$
Just don't try to eliminate the *f* bilinears by (2.10) because you are stuck.

I strongly urge you to use the more abstract invariants' structure leading up to them, instead of obsessing with parochial identities, however.

Back to (2), e.g. for *su(3)*, the fully symmetric *d*s are properties of the Gell-Mann matrix basis, not the algebra,
$$
4 d^{ijk}=\operatorname {Tr} (\{ \lambda^i,\lambda^j\}\lambda^k).
$$
You can read up in you standard text that they vanish when the number of indices from the set {2,5,7} is odd, from evident antisymmetry of the Gell-Mann  matrices in that basis.

The nonvanishing independent elements are, naturally, (cf D B Lichtenberg, *Unitary Symmetry & Elementary Particles*):

$1/\sqrt 3$ for {118,228,338} ;

$-1/\sqrt 3$  for 888;

$-1/2\sqrt3$ for {448,558,668,778};

1/2 for {344,355,146,157,256};

-1/2 for {247,366,377}.

As indicated, simplification is somewhat subjective.

Comment: Do you know https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236324/79069 for semi-simple Lie algebra?  $f^{abc}$ can be totally antisymmetric for semi-simple Lie algebra I think?

Comment: You may indeed arrange $-i2\operatorname{tr}(\lambda_c[\lambda_a,\lambda_b])=f_{abc}$ fully antisymmetric for semisimple ones. Will go to that question next.

Comment: As I comment there (2.10) of [McF, S & W](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01654302.pdf) is derived for semi simple ones in their method.

Comment: I think your values for the elements of $d$ are incorrect, e.g. 344
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group

Comment: @Rudyard Thanks, you certainly appear to be right: the $\sqrt 3$s come from contamination by $\lambda_8$. Unfortunately I don't recall my source for what I have. Will fix in time.

Comment: yes unfortunately there seem to be several bad sources out there. Here's one I would trust. page 10 of https://cds.cern.ch/record/328129/files/9706006.pdf

Comment: Looks fixed now, *even* in WP. Lichtenberg's text cited is the classic go-to.