# Improve Lie algebra structure constant formula $f^{abc} f^{ade} \propto \delta^{b,d}\delta^{c,e}-\delta^{b,e}\delta^{c,d} + ...?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, compact-manifolds

This is really a simple naive question.

We know Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon^{abc}$ has a nice property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Proofs
$$
\epsilon^{abc} \epsilon^{ade}=\delta^{b,d}\delta^{c,e}-\delta^{b,e}\delta^{c,d}
$$

$\delta^{i,j}$ is the delta function between $i,j$. Here $a$ is summed over as $\sum_{a}$.

Is there any Lie algebra structure constant formula similar to the above for 
$$f^{abc} f^{ade},$$ has any simplified form?
Say,
$$f^{abc} f^{ade}=\delta^{b,d}\delta^{c,e}-\delta^{b,e}\delta^{c,d}  + ...?$$

If so, can you give a Reference or suggest where to find a proof (if you do not want to prove it).

- We can consider for example semi-simple Lie algebra?
- We can also consider compact semi-simple Lie group.
- see another question too: [Symmetric tensor of Lie algebra of $su(N)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877927/79069)

Comment: Yes and no. Your formula is just too special for SU(2), which, exceptionally!, has vanishing symmetric $d_{abc}$ coefficients. The generalization, at least for SU(N), involves those as well, e.g. eqn (2.10) of [McFarlane, Sudbery & Weisz, 1968](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01654302.pdf).

Comment: I added  $+ ...$

Comment: Well, it appears this type of identity for su(N) is a consequence of the equivalent gl(N) involved, which does not bode well for so(N) or sp(N) to say the least, and I would not dare speculate for the exceptionals. So, the pretty formula invoving bilinears of $\delta$s and *d* s seems restricted to su(N).